# I want to implement docker in spring and hibernate application using gradle

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, docker

I had develop an application using gradle and spring-Hibernate. Now i want to implement docker in the same. Can somebody tell me how to proceed. i read many tutorials of docker but unable to get the right resource.

Comment: I take it you deploy your application to Tomcat or Jetty ?
Then simply grab a docker snapshot of Tomcat / Jetty and package your application into one of the pre-built images:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/
https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/jetty/

Comment: Please provide your research with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will develop your application the same way then before. Additionally you would create a `Dockerfile` that uses the [`java` image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/java/) as parent. As a `CMD` you pass a `java -jar ...` command. More details you can find on the provided link above.